# Android: Samsung S4 Screen size

Tags: android, samsung-mobile

I am trying to figure out the dimensions for the S4. What is the width and height. I want to create graphics and place them based on h and w. I read that the screen size ranges from 0-h and 0-w, but what are h and w?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's some handy code if you need to find the size of various devices:

```
Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
Point size = new Point();
display.getSize(size);
int screenWidth = size.x;
int screenHeight = size.y;
```

Answer (score 3):

S4 screen specs are 1080 x 1920, but **you shouldn't use the actual screen size in pixels in your code**.
Just use dp - which is a size which is independent in the screen density to design you Android app UI, this way, it will behave nicely for all screen sizes.
For more details see [Supporting Multiple Screens Guidelines](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html).